# Running Windows Containers on Windows Server 2019 but Developing on Windows 10

Tags: docker, virtual-machines, asp.net, windows-server-2019

I have docker running on a server machine running Windows Server 2019 - 1809, to which I want to deploy an ASP .NET Core 3.1 Web API within a Windows container.

I am developing this web API on my dev VM with Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2019.

Since the 2 machines require different base images to run a container, what is the recommended approach here to develop on the Win10 and then deploy to WinServer? Is this even possible?